# Can't access value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
scala> val blank_line_accumulator = sc.accumulator(0,"Blank Lines")
blank_line_accumulator: org.apache.spark.Accumulator[Int] = 0

val input_file2 = sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/input2.txt").foreach{x=>if(x.length()==0)blank_line_accumulator +=1}
input_file2: Unit = ()
```

> scala> input_file2.value :40: error: value value is not a
>   member of Unit
>                 input_file2.value

This is my problem while accessing the Value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error for me to access the value it worked like a charm.. may be you are doing some simple mistake somewher else. take fresh spark-shell and try again..

```
scala> blank_line_accumulator.value
res3: Int = 3
```

to debug this try below... should give `Class[Int] = int`

```
scala> blank_line_accumulator.value.getClass
res4: Class[Int] = int
```

and try to debug `scala> blank_line_accumulator.getClass`
should give below...

```
res6: Class[_ <: org.apache.spark.Accumulator[Int]] = class  
 org.apache.spark.Accumulator
```

Comment: were you able use the above approach

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` doesn't return any useful value, which is represented as [`Unit`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/Unit.html) (which you can see in the type: `input_file2: Unit = ()`). `Unit` doesn't have a `value`, so there's nothing to access. Probably you meant `blank_line_accumulator.value` as Ram Ghadiyaram's answer shows.